# json_decode returns null value from iOS application

Tags: php, ios, json

I am having trouble parsing data sent to a php webservice. I am using the following code to get the json:

```
$decoded = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
if(is_null($decoded) == NULL)
    {
        $body = "Data was not successfully received";
        $body = $body . "      " . $jsonInput;
    }
```

The json is sent from an iOS application and looks like the following:

```
{
  "water" : "YES",
  "int_clean" : "YES",
  "ceiling_stains" : "YES",
  "additional_comments" : "not entered",
  "roof_cond" : "YES",
  "e_clean" : "YES",
  "interior_cond" : "not entered",
  "no_exp" : "not entered",
  "addr" : "YES",
  "roof_leak" : "YES",
  "doors_sec" : "YES",
  "elec" : "YES",
  "ceiling_exp" : "not entered",
  "repaired" : "YES",
  "o_desc" : "not entered",
  "w_sign" : "YES",
  "o_cond" : "not entered",
  "int_cond" : "YES",
  "gas" : "YES",
  "for_sale_sign" : "YES",
  "sold_as_is" : "YES",
  "mb_sign" : "YES",
  "graffiti" : "YES",
  "date" : "18-12-2012 18:58",
  "dewinterized" : "YES",
  "HVAC" : "YES",
  "why_no_mat" : "not entered",
  "is_lockbox" : "YES",
  "financing_mat" : "YES",
  "yard_cond" : "YES",
  "marketing_mat" : "YES",
  "HVAC_missing" : "not entered",
  "agent_info" : "YES",
  "e_cond" : "YES",
  "e_key" : "YES",
  "pool_sec" : "YES",
  "pool_clean" : "YES"
}
```

And sending it with this code:

```
 NSDictionary * info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:info options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://uofi-bars.com/sendEmail.php"]];
[req addValue:@"Content-Type: application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:jsonData];


[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

I am completely new to php and this has been giving me a headache for quite some time. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `if(is_null($decoded) == NULL)`? why not `if(is_null($decoded))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct `if(is_null($decoded) == NULL)`. `PHP is_null` returns a `boolean` value. So you need to be using `if(is_null($decoded) === FALSE)` or `if(is_null($decoded) === TRUE)`.